# My google action works perfectly when tested on the test console but does not on the actual device

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

Specifically, after the action shows a Carousel and the user selects one item, the actions fails to respond on the android device and I see no error in the firebase logs. 
The action works as intended on the test console in phone mode.
Is there anyway to understand what's going wrong?

Comment: You can check [your Action's logs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/troubleshooting?hl=ja#troubleshooting) to find more information about what could be failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem got solved automatically after some updates to the google assistant.